# Why does filling in a rectangle on a canvas degrade performance slowly?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I'm currently working on a HTML5 game that utilizes a `<canvas>` element. I'm mysteriously suffering performance degradation in the program as time passes, and was hoping you could perhaps explain the behavior.

I have traced the problem to a function that paints the background of each frame. In gist it appears as:

```
function paintBackground() {
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"
  ctx.fill()
}
```

I've also setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp354car/3/) representing this scenario.

The interesting thing about this piece of code is that when measured, it slowly becomes less efficient by order of a few magnitudes. Using the JSFiddle as an example, it begins with the function taking less than a millisecond to complete. About 2-3 seconds later, it is reporting it to now take about 1 millisecond. About 10 seconds in, it's now averaging between 2-3 milliseconds. Within a minute it averages about 6-7 milliseconds, and when I let it run for about 5 minutes, it got as high as 13-14 milliseconds. This is hundreds of percent slower than when it started, with nothing changing! I have tested identical pieces of code in IE 11 and Firefox 35.0.1. Both show the same degradation, but it seems to go downhill slightly faster in Firefox.

Now, I'm not someone who fusses over microoptimisations, but my goal is to hit a solid 60FPS, which means I only have ~16.67ms for rendering and updates, and I'm basically gradually losing half of that alone just by rendering the background! I'm also worried that this might be a runaway train, and who knows how bad performance might get; potentially rendering my game unplayable.

As far as I can tell, this is the only factor contributing to the performance degradation for two reasons: 1) The rest of the game code is running smoothly, including rendering all of the tiles (375+ tiles per frame) that make up a level, and 2) I experience this behavior even in the JSFiddle provided which includes nothing but that rectangle fill.

Any explanations or suggestions on this behavior would really be enlightening!

P.S. I know this may sound stupid, but is anyone else experience this behavior? or is it just me? I should note though that my CPU is slow enough (1.4ghz dual-core) to make this noticeable.

Comment: Confirmed to degrade in IE11 and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

The `rect()` command will add to the path and accumulate, so each time you call `fill()` all the previous rect's are filled as well.

Solve in one of two ways:

```
function paintBackground() {
  ctx.beginPath(); // RESET path here
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

or fill directly without using the path:

```
function paintBackground() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Also use requestAnimationFrame for better animations.

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp354car/5/)**

Ps: don't forget the semi-columns.